# Laravel Illegal operator and value combination on where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

There are more than 10 controllers in my project. They all have the same code, only the table names are different.

Exactly 2 of these controllers have a problem with the shared host that is 'Illegal operator and value combination'. Surprisingly other controllers works without making such a mistake.
Maybe I overlooked something.

That's where the 'Illegal operator and value combination' problem comes from.

```
$tarifs = DB::table('tarifs as tarif')
            ->join('companies as comp', 'tarif.company_id','=', 'comp.id')
            ->join('categories as cats', 'tarif.catid', '=', 'cats.id')
            ->where('tarif.company_id', '<', env('COMKEY'))
            ->get(['tarif.*', 'comp.name', 'comp.photo as cimage','cats.cat_uz']);
```

Showing this line as an error  `->where('tarif.company_id', '<', env('COMKEY'))`

This one works without errors.

```
 $minutes = DB::table('minutes as minute')
        ->join('companies as comp', 'minute.company_id','=', 'comp.id')
        ->join('categories as cats', 'minute.catid', '=', 'cats.id')
        ->where('minute.company_id', '<', env('COMKEY'))
        ->get(['minute.*', 'comp.name', 'cats.cat_uz']);
```

The project is running normally and without errors on localhost.
Shared and local php versions are the same 7.4

Comment: DB::enableQueryLog(); print_r(DB::getQueryLog()); 
can you try to put query log and paste the query here ?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [query] => select `tarif`.*, `comp`.`name`, `comp`.`photo` 
          as `cimage`, `cats`.`cat_uz` from `tarifs` as `tarif` inner join `companies` as `comp` 
        on `tarif`.`company_id` = `comp`.`id` inner join `categories` as `cats` on `tarif`.`catid` 
       = `cats`.`id` where `tarif`.`company_id` < ? [bindings] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [time] => 
          24.14 ) )`   here is log

Comment: make sure comparison value can not be a null  look like env('COMKEY') return a null. can you try to put a static value there ?

Comment: env('COMKEY')  has static value. I put the static value to the query but result is same. 
llegal operator and value combination.
           `  ->where('tarif.company_id', '<', '10')`

Comment: Thank you @jaydeep-chauhan.
'COMKEY' information in the .env file on the shared hosting was incorrect, we did not pay attention to it. Problem is solved

Comment: I would also suggest to not get the value directly from `.env` file. You can pass `env('COMKEY')` first in `config/app.php` and catch it from there using `config('...')`

Answer (score 1):

When `env('COMKEY')` returns the null you will get this error:

> InvalidArgumentException with message 'Illegal operator and value combination.'

Code:

```
$minutes =  DB::table('tarifs as tarif')
            ->join('companies as comp', 'tarif.company_id','=', 'comp.id')
            ->join('categories as cats', 'tarif.catid', '=', 'cats.id')
            ->when($comKey,function($query) use ($comKey){
              logger()->info('Comkey value is not null',[
                'comKey'=> $comKey
              ]);
              return $query->where('tarif.company_id', '<', env('COMKEY'));
            },function($query) use ($comKey){
              logger()->info('Comkey value is null');
              return $query;
            })
        ->dd();
```

Please use the above query to debug your query.

If the value is returned from env the log will be something like

```
Comkey value is not null {"comKey":"RandomKey"}
```

If the value is returned from env the log will be something like:

```
Comkey value is null
```